# Underlining text in Excel automation

Tags: excel, automation

I'm using Delphi for Excel automation. I want to underline the text in cell A3, like I did manually in cell A1 (see screenshot).

[image]

As you can see the underlining spans the whole cell width, instead of just the text.
What I tried:

```
WS.Cells[3,1].Font.Underline := xlUnderlineStyleDoubleAccounting;
```

and

```
WS.Cells[3,1].Characters[1,4].Font.Underline := xlUnderlineStyleDoubleAccounting;
```

to no avail. Note that the underlining in A3 refers indeed to the text, and not the cell border, like I show in B3.
How can I use automation to get the same result as I get when formatting manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Microsoft's enumeration documentation there are two different types of double underlining:

```
xlUnderlineStyleDouble           -4119  Double thick underline.
xlUnderlineStyleDoubleAccounting     5  Two thin underlines placed close together.
```

Using the former gives the desired result.

Note: The documentation talks about thick and thin underlines, but in my spreadsheet the thickness is the same. There is however a difference in distance from the text:

[image]